# How do I clear this list at the end of every loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the maximum value for different subsets of a list.

```
def max_value(filename):
    CHR=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', 'X']

    SNP = [ ]

    chr_max=[ ]

    for n in CHR:
        for r in reader:
            if r[1]==n:
                SNP.append(r[2])        #append values into empty list SNP
        SNP = [try_int(x) for x in SNP] #convert to integers
        max_val=max(SNP)                #find the maximum value
        chr_max.append((n, max_val))    #append this maximum to a new list
        del SNP[:]                      #clear the list and loop for next item in CHR list

    return chr_max
```

I keep getting

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

When I remove the del SNP[:] step I get output, but it returns the max value for n='1'(since it is the maximum value overall it gets returned for all 20 loops, if i do not empty clear the list).

How do I clear the SNP list at the end of each loop, so I can find the maximum value for different subsets of the list?

Comment: And what is `reader`?

Comment: Also consider using something like `max(map(int, <your_list>))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse the `reader` and `CHR` loops so you only loop `reader` once:

```
SNPs = {}
for r in reader:
    for n in CHR:
        if r[1]==n:
            SNPs.setdefault(n, []).append(r[2])        #append values into empty list SNP
for n in CHR:
    SNP = SNPs[n]
    # I didn't change anything below here..
    SNP = [try_int(x) for x in SNP] #convert to integers
    max_val=max(SNP)                #find the maximum value
    chr_max.append((n, max_val))    #append this maximum to a new list
```

Note you can also use

```
from itertools import defaultdict
SNPs = defaultdict(list)
```

and change the append to:

```
SNPs[n].append(r[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

If `reader` is a file object or `csv.reader()` object, you cannot loop over it multiple times and expect it to start from the beginning again.

A file object would need to be rewound to the start with `reader.seek(0)`, for example.

As a consequence, the second time your code reaches the `for r in reader:` loop, the loop terminates immediately without executing any iterations, no new elements are added to `SNP` and it remains empty.

You could just sort the input from the `reader` iterable into a dictionary instead of continues looping:

```
CHR=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', 'X']
values = {c: [] for c in CHR}
for row in reader:
    if row[1] in values:
        values[row[1]].append(try_int(row[2]))

return [max(values[c]) for c in CHR if values[c]]
```

Comment: This works.  I just had to change 'for row in reader' to 'for r in reader'.  Thanks

Comment: @user3204333: sorry, yes, my mistake.

Comment: @user3204333: otherwise, glad both answers helped you. Unfortunately, you can only mark *one* of them as accepted, not both.